# visual studio 2010 free svn repository with agile support

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, agile, ankhsvn

What is your recommendations for a free svn server supporting visual studio ?

inclunding / or compatible with other Agile free tools.

For small teamwork, 2/3

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use [assembla.com](http://assembla.com) for small projects. It has a free plan with 1GB of space.

Comment: Hi, Thanks Ashton for your your advice, I didn' t know that assembly is free up to 1Gb ! :), that' s really a good new, I see that it support Agile as well, but not free, do you know any good free agile too which can be connected with assembla ?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not a big fan of subversion, I mainly use git :) As far as I know assembla offers free agile for opensource projects. You may also want to try [targetprocess](http://www.targetprocess.com/), they have a free plan for 5 users, though I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: Hi, I have make a tried on target process, the webinterface is really good, however integration in visual studio is too basic, cannot see all the stories to make the change for example

Answer (score 1):

I recommend for :

***Planning & Tracking***

**Version one :**   a very good tool that supports scrum and kanban & the team edition is for free , also , it has a plug-in for vs which make it very handy for team members to update their efforts.

***Source control***

I've used both SVN (2 years ) & git using github (1 year) and I'd definitely vote for git it is more flexible than SVN -from my personal point of view , also , github has its own built-in issue tracking , code review and wiki which is a big plus as u'll be using only one tool and for free.

git has its GuI clients for windows OS and if you are using linux based distro it will be much more fun and easier to use.

Having said that the draw back in the free account is that your repository will be public (anyone can access your code).

[Versionone link](http://www.versionone.com/pricing_and_editions/)

[github features link](https://github.com/features/projects)

Good luck ...

Comment: thanks for your answer, I didn' t know about version one, I will definitely give it a try, that sounds really good, with a visual studio plug in, as I am planning a private project, Git won' t be the solution as it is public, can you make a git project private somehow ?

Comment: The statement that Git is more flexible than SVN is questionable and I'd never agree with that!

Comment: Why do you think / or not that Gib is more flexible than SVN ?

Comment: @dtjmsy To create a private github you'll need you’ll need to upgrade your account from Free to Micro & it will cost $7.00/month.

Comment: @bahrep you have every right to question/not agree with it I should have mentioned that it is my opinion not absolute one based on my experience with both tools , I'll edit the comment to be more clear thanks for your feedback.